# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared in Vite React Project after installing opensea-js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, opensea

I'm working on a React project using Vite, and recently started encountering an error after installing the opensea-js package. The error message I'm seeing is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Buffer' has already been declared (at chunk-EXX7LTSE.js?v=970d3bc1:19:3)
```

Here is the relevant part of my vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr'
import { NgmiPolyfill } from 'vite-plugin-ngmi-polyfill'

export default defineConfig({
  envDir: './env',
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    NgmiPolyfill({
      rollupPolyfillOptions: {}
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
      alias: { timers: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers' },
  },
  build: {
      sourcemap: true,
  },
})
```

---

Package versions in package.json:

```
"buffer": "^6.0.3",
"opensea-js": "^5.0.2",
```

I have the buffer package installed in my project. My understanding is that opensea-js and possibly other dependencies are using the Buffer global, which is causing a conflict.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What might be causing this conflict, and how can I resolve it?

I appreciate any insights or help!

Comment: Hey there. I'm having the same issue with a similar implementation. Did you ever find a solution?